# Uninstall / remove a Homebrew package including all its dependencies

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have a **Homebrew** formula that I wish to uninstall/remove along with all its dependencies, skipping packages whom other packages depend upon (a.k.a. [Cascading package removal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager#Cascading_package_removal) in Package manager parlance).

*e.g.* Uninstall package `a` which depends on packages `b` & `c`, where package `d` also depends on package `c`. The result should uninstall both `a` & `b`, skipping `c`.

How can I do that?

There must be a way to uninstall a package without leaving unnecessary *junk* behind.

Comment: Isn't this what any package manager, worth this name, should do out-of-the-box?! LOL

Comment: As of 2021, [`brew autoremove`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719581/619961) is what you're looking for:

Answer (score 511, accepted):

### EDIT:

It looks like [the issue is now solved using an external command called `brew rmdeps` or `brew rmtree`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7465#issuecomment-4998005).

To install and use, issue the following commands:

```
$ brew tap beeftornado/rmtree
$ brew rmtree <package>
```

See the above link for more information and discussion.

---

[EDIT] see the new command `brew autoremove` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66719581/160968

---

### Original answer:

It appears that currently, there's no easy way to accomplish this.

However, I [filed an issue on Homebrew's GitHub page](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7465), and somebody suggested a temporary solution until they add an exclusive command to solve this.

There's an [external command](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/External-Commands) called `brew leaves` which prints all packages that are not dependencies of other packages.

If you do a logical ***and*** on the output of `brew leaves` and `brew deps <package>`, you might just get a list of the orphaned dependency packages, which you can uninstall manually afterwards. Combine this with `xargs` and you'll get what you need, I guess (untested, don't count on this).

---

**EDIT:** Somebody just suggested a very similar solution, using `join` instead of `xargs`:

```
brew rm FORMULA
brew rm $(join <(brew leaves) <(brew deps FORMULA))
```

---

See the [comment on the issue mentioned above](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7465#issuecomment-2027137) for more info.

Comment: In 2020 this solution seems to be the best of all worlds presented herein. It's worthwile to mention that most of the time after purging a lot of packages, the following is needed ```brew cleanup -s && \rm -rf "$(brew --cache)"```

Comment: brew rmtree does not work at all!

Answer (score 395):

**By the end of 2020, the Homebrew team added a simple command `brew autoremove` to remove all unused dependencies.**

First, uninstall the package:

`brew uninstall <package>`

Then, remove all the unused dependencies:

`brew autoremove`

Comment: This also removes some packages that are listed in brewfile, why is that?

Comment: @stevemao Try asking the Homebrew team.

Comment: If you run `export HOMEBREW_AUTOREMOVE=1` then `brew uninstall` will automatically run autoremove

Comment: I saw gazillions of packages installed with mysql. I did `brew uinstall mysql`, then `brew autoremove` and only 4 formulae were identified for removal. Does this work like I think and/or are packages incorrectly identified as dependencies vs. not?

Comment: this should be the first attempt/approach in 2024

Answer (score 46):

`brew rmtree` [doesn't work at all](https://github.com/beeftornado/homebrew-rmtree/issues/14). From the links on that issue I found [rmrec](https://github.com/ggPeti/homebrew-rmrec) which actually does work. God knows why `brew` doesn't have this as a native command.

```
brew tap ggpeti/rmrec
brew rmrec pkgname
```

Comment: Really LOVE this, though if you've already started down the path of uninstalling yourself and keep finding more packages you need to remove, you still need to know what are the widest touching packages, or you can just briefly reinstall the `[FORMULA]` and then use rmrec to recursively remove all it's dependencies properly.

Comment: Caveat: It also appears `rmrec` doesn't currently handle namespaced packages very well. I was using something that pulled in `linuxbrew/xorg/xorg` and it removed everything except that package and even explicitly naming that package it couldn't resolve it and did nothing.

Comment: Confirmed that recommendation to use `rmrec` is bad. It does not handle dependencies at all.

Comment: You mean `rmtree`? `rmrec` does handle dependencies.

Comment: `God knows why brew doesn't have this as a native command.` => Because brew developers have bad attitudes. They don't even allow people to open any issues. Check https://github.com/Homebrew/brew, it only has less than 20 issues now. Such a small number. Is that a good thing? No, it's very bad.

Comment: The beauty of this solution is the simplicity of the script and that it works quite well. **It needs to be made recursive to remove the dependencies of dependencies and their dependencies**.

Comment: @Timmmm it seems the `rmtree` issue linked to in your comment has been fixed for a while now https://github.com/beeftornado/homebrew-rmtree/issues/14

Answer (score 38):

The goal here is to remove the given package and its dependencies **without** breaking another package's dependencies. I use this command:

```
brew deps [FORMULA] | xargs brew remove --ignore-dependencies && brew missing | xargs brew install
```

Note: Edited to reflect @alphadogg's helpful comment.

Comment: Had to add `--ignore-dependencies` to remove to allow this to work.

Comment: This broke my brew configuration, as it did not reinstall the deps that are used in other packages. DONT USE

Answer (score 22):

Based on @jfmercer answer (corrections needed more than a comment).

Remove package's dependencies (does not remove package):

```
brew deps [FORMULA] | xargs brew remove --ignore-dependencies
```

Remove package:

```
brew remove [FORMULA]
```

Reinstall missing libraries:

```
brew missing | cut -d: -f2 | sort | uniq | xargs brew install
```

Tested uninstalling `meld` after discovering [MeldMerge releases](https://github.com/yousseb/meld/releases).

Comment: I had installed ffmpeg with brew, which messed things up severely. Cleaning up ffmpeg, including its extended list of dependencies, with the method described above, worked for me.

Comment: For me `brew deps` show different packages than those that shown after `brew uninstall ` attempt.

Answer (score 13):

Using this answer requires that you create and maintain a file that contains the package names you want installed on your system.  If you don't have one already, use the following command and delete the package names what you don't want to keep installed.

```
brew leaves > brew_packages
```

Then you can remove all installed, but unwanted packages and any unnecessary dependencies by running the following command

```
brew_clean brew_packages
```

`brew_clean` is available here: https://gist.github.com/cskeeters/10ff1295bca93808213d

This script gets all of the packages you specified in brew_packages and all of their dependancies and compares them against the output of `brew list` and finally removes the unwanted packages after verifying this list with the user.

At this point if you want to remove package `a`, you simply remove it from the brew_packages file then re-run `brew_clean brew_packages`.  It will remove `b`, but not `c`.

Comment: I think brew clean is built-in now, try `brew clean -s`

Comment: ABOVE COMMENT WAS WRONG, editing cuts off at 5 minutes. try `brew cleanup -s && brew cask cleanup`

Answer (score 12):

Save the following script as **brew-purge**

```
#!/bin/bash
#:Usage: brew purge formula
#: 
#:Removes the package and all dependancies.
#: 
#: 
PKG="$1"
if [ -z "$PKG" ];then
   brew purge --help
   exit 1
fi
brew rm $PKG
[ $? -ne 0 ] && exit 1
while brew rm $(join <(brew leaves) <(brew deps $PKG)) 2>/dev/null
  do :
done
echo Package $PKG and its dependancies have been removed.
exit 0
```

Now install it with the following command

```
sudo install brew-purge /usr/local/bin
```

Now run it

```
brew purge package
```

Example using gpg

```
$ brew purge gpg
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.2.13... (134 files, 11.0MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/adns/1.5.1... (14 files, 597.5KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/gnutls/3.6.6... (1,200 files, 8.9MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.8.4... (21 files, 2.6MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.5... (14 files, 344.2KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libusb/1.0.22... (29 files, 508KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/npth/1.6... (11 files, 71.7KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/pinentry/1.1.0_1... (12 files, 263.9KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libassuan/2.5.3... (16 files, 444.2KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libtasn1/4.13... (59 files, 436KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libunistring/0.9.10... (54 files, 4.4MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/nettle/3.4.1... (85 files, 2MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/p11-kit/0.23.15... (63 files, 2.9MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2... (18 files, 3.1MB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.2.1... (16 files, 296.8KB)
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/libgpg-error/1.35... (27 files, 854.8KB)
Package gpg and its dependancies have been removed.
$
```

Answer (score 4):

### A More-Complete Bourne Shell Function

There are a number of good answers already, but some are out of date and none of them are entirely complete. In particular, most of them will remove dependencies but still leave it up to you to remove the originally-targeted formula afterwards. The posted one-liners can also be tedious to work with if you want to uninstall more than one formula at a time.

Here is a Bourne-compatible shell function (without any known Bashisms) that takes a list of formulae, removes each one's dependencies, removes all copies of the formula itself, and then reinstalls any missing dependencies.

```
unbrew () {
    local formula
    for formula in "$@"; do
        brew deps "$formula" |
        xargs brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force
        brew uninstall --force "$formula"
    done
    brew missing | cut -f2 -d: | sort -u | xargs brew install
}
```

It was tested on Homebrew 1.7.4.

### Caveats

This works on all standard formulae that I tested. It does not presently handle casks, but neither will it complain loudly if you attempt to unbrew a cask with the same name as a standard formula (e.g. MacVim).

Comment: This started to uninstalled my packages randomly and broke my brew configuration, and zsh

Answer (score 3):

You can just use a UNIX pipe for this

```
brew deps [FORMULA] | xargs brew rm
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution. You can break other packages' dependencies this way.

Comment: There is a command you can run afterwards to tell you if you nuked any other required dependencies `brew missing` which will tell you what command you need to run to get them back

Answer (score 3):

Other answers didn't work for me, but this did (in `fish` shell):

```
brew remove <package>
for p in (brew deps <package>)
    brew remove $p
end
```

Because `brew remove $p` fails when some other package depends on `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly refined; can supply multiple packages; has usage when none supplied.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Removes the package and all dependancies.

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "$(basename $0) <pkg> [<pkg> [...]]"
   exit 1
fi

function tree() {
    pkg="$1"
    join <(brew leaves) <(sort <(brew deps ${pkg}; echo ${pkg}))
} 

let e=0
for pkg in "$@"; do
    printf "Purging %s and its dependencies...\n" "${pkg}"
    deps=( $(tree ${pkg}) )
    while (( ${#deps[@]} > 0 )); do
        brew rm "${deps[@]}"
        deps=( $(tree ${pkg}) )
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @jfmercer must be modified slightly to work with current brew, because the output of `brew missing` has changed:

```
brew deps [FORMULA] | xargs brew remove --ignore-dependencies && brew missing | cut -f1 -d: | xargs brew install
```