# homebrew uninstall ruby

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I just installed ruby via

> brew install ruby

I have been advised to install it via RVM, even if I use Homebrew, but first  I want to uninstall the ruby that homebrew just installed.

Can I simply do

> brew uninstall ruby

Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323261/uninstall-remove-a-homebrew-package-including-all-its-dependencies

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, `brew uninstall ruby` should do the trick.

For more info, you can type `man brew` in your terminal.

Answer (score 7):

Doing `brew uninstall ruby` will work. If you really want to be sure, you can run `brew cleanup` after running the first command. Homebrew just removes unnecessary packages with the `brew cleanup` command. In some cases, the last command is necessary for the formula to be completely gone. (An example is with the `tree` formula, I had to use `brew cleanup` for it to be entirely uninstalled.)

(I know this is late but this can apply to anyone who is viewing this)

Comment: It won't work because of the updated security 
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.

Answer (score 1):

This might help other people who used rbenv to manage their ruby versions & have installed rbenv using the command below

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build
```

You can uninstall ruby by

```
brew uninstall rbenv && brew uninstall ruby-build
```

You can refer to the Installing Ruby section of this [guide](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11-big-sur).