# Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0.a) among 48 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

```
Mac OS 10.15.7


ABCD-MBP:~ abcd$ which ruby
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby

ABCD-MBP:~ abcd$ ruby -v
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

pod setup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    3: from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
    2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
    1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0.a) among 48 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/abcd/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

I'm not getting why old version of ruby is getting referred here ?

With XCode > pod install is failing as old version of ruby is getting referred as well.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
        2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
        1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:323:in `to_spec'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0.a) among 48 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/abcd/.gem/ruby/2.6.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0', execute `gem env` for more information
```

I tried different solutions proposed in SO but couldn't get this fixed

- uninstall all gems and install again
- uninstall pod and install again

Comment: Cocoapods [install documentation](https://cocoapods.org) says "We recommend you use the default ruby", which is the one in `/usr/bin/ruby`.  I'm not a cocoapods user, so I don't know if that's wired into the `pods` command or can be overridden by doing the `gem install cocoapods` command using `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/gem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happens when default Mac has got different ruby version that one you have installed

I could solve this by installing same ruby version as Mac OS ruby framework.
Remove all gems, reinstall pod again.

References

1. https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/10246#issuecomment-761719446
2. https://superuser.com/questions/340490/how-to-install-and-use-different-versions-of-ruby
3. https://rvm.io/rvm/install
4. https://jeffreymorgan.io/articles/ruby-on-macos-with-rvm/
5. https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4215
6. [Uninstall all installed gems, in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095209/uninstall-all-installed-gems-in-osx)
7. [homebrew uninstall ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288391/homebrew-uninstall-ruby)
8. https://rvm.io/rubies/default

I wonder what kind of fun Apple engineers get to make pod + ruby such complex thing to fix :)