# Mono on OS X shows old version after installing latest version

Tags: macos, mono

I just installed Mono 3.10.0 on OS X using the package from their website.
Before the installation I had installed 3.6.1.

After the installation of 3.10.0 `mono --version` still shows `3.6.1`.

`which mono` returns `/usr/local/bin/mono`.

In `/usr/local/bin/`, mono refs to:

`mono -> ../Cellar/kmono/3.6.1-10002/bin/mono`.

Where can I find and activate my recently installed version 3.10.0?

`~/Library/Frameworks/mono` does not exist.

Comment: "Cellar/kmono" means you installed the custom Mono version from ProjectK/ASP.NET vNext via homebrew. Remove that version (vNext now works with official Mono).

Comment: I already tried brew uninstall but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Maybe try the steps outlined in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323261/uninstall-remove-a-homebrew-package-including-all-its-dependencies to get rid of the homebrew mono.

Comment: Just tried ```brew uninstall kmono``` and `brew uninstall mono``` again. Then reinstalled the mono package again and everything works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have a custom mono in your /usr/local, which takes precedence over the one you just installed. You need to remove your custom one.

Your recently installed mono can be found in /usr (try `/usr/bin/mono --version`, and it will print 3.10)

Comment: Thanks, there's no ```/usr/bin/mono```. ```/usr/bin/mono --version``` also returns ```3.6.1```

Comment: I've found another folder ```/usr/local/etc/mono``` which contains subfolders ```2.0```, ```4.0```, ```4.5``` and the creation date matches yesterday when I installed ```3.10.0```
. But calling ```mono --version``` inside the folder still returns ```3.6.1```