# Homebrew find installed packages which aren't dependencies of any other installed package

Tags: homebrew, xargs

Previously I've had things installed with homebrew which had dependencies which I omitted to remove when I removed the package itself (homebrew of course [does not do this automatically for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323261/uninstall-remove-a-homebrew-package-including-all-its-dependencies), for good reason).

Now, to tidy up my system a bit, I'd like to identify all the brew packages which are not required by any other that is installed, so that I can manually identify those which I want to keep vs. those I am happy to remove.

To do this manually, I would do `brew list`, then, on each item which that outputs, I would do `brew uses --installed <name-of-package-from-brew-list>`, to check with respect to each package whether it is used by any other installed package *(Then, if the answer is none, if I was curious as to why it was originally installed, I could also do `brew uses <name-of-installed-package>` which might indicate to me which package I used in the past but have since uninstalled actually installed it originally)*.

This is all very manual and I wondered if xargs could help.

My attempt to use it isn't working:

`brew list | xargs brew uses --installed > test.txt`

I get no output at all from that command, a blank file (but the command takes several seconds to run).

What am I not doing right with `xargs`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems like `brew leaves` would fit your use-case?

```
% brew leaves --help
Usage: brew leaves

List installed formulae that are not dependencies of another installed formula.
```

From the question:

```
brew list | xargs brew uses --installed > test.txt
```

This command should be spelled `xargs -n1` since `brew uses` with multiple formulae does something quite different:

```
% brew uses --help
Usage: brew uses [options] formula

Show formulae that specify formula as a dependency. When given multiple
formula arguments, show the intersection of formulae that use formula. By
default, uses shows all formulae that specify formula as a required or
recommended dependency for their stable builds.
```

Comment: nice, thanks. i saw discussion of `leaves` but didn't realise it was in homebrew itself. fyi re. the part of the question specifically about xargs, i simply added `-n1` to the xargs command above, but that still doesn't do as wished, some extra loop going on.

Answer (score 11):

```
brew autoremove --dry-run
```

Removes all packages that were only installed as a dependency of another formula and are now no longer needed. With the `--dry-run` flag you can dry run it and just get a list of all packages without uninstalling anything.