# How do I reinstall a package with all its dependencies?

Tags: homebrew, package-managers

`brew reinstall` only reinstalls the package itself, not its dependencies. I want to reinstall them all.

Comment: This is a site about programming, not general computer/software questions.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Precedent for questions like these has already been set on Stack Overflow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323261/uninstall-remove-a-homebrew-package-including-all-its-dependencies?rq=1

However, I do agree that Super User is probably more appropriate: https://superuser.com/

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica - totally normal question for SO tbh, we have a tag `homebrew` and it's a CLI-tool, not like sombody asks how to change wallpaper on windows 7 :)

Answer (score 4):

The following command should do the trick:

```
brew reinstall $(brew deps package) package
```

...where "package" is the name of the package you would like to reinstall.