# Something like pip-tools for homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, pip-tools

When you install something with [homebrew](https://brew.sh), it also installs the dependencies, which is fine. But later, when you deinstall this specific item, the dependencies remain installed. So by time, you have a lot of software installed and don't know why.

For [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/), where the situation is similar, there are solutions like [pip-tools](https://pypi.org/project/pip-tools/). You have to curate a list with the packages you want (`requirements.in`) and with `pip-compile` you get the list af *all* packages, including the dependencies (`requirements.txt`). When you delete an entry in the `requirements.in` and re-compile, the dependencies also vanish in `requirements.txt`, as long as they aren't needed for something else.

I wonder if there's something similar for homebrew?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333289/2836621

Comment: Yes, the link to `brew autoremove` there is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here’s command to list unused dependencies:

```
$ brew leaves --installed-as-dependency
```

Or:

```
$ brew autoremove --dry-run
```

To uninstall them:

```
$ brew autoremove
```